# Oracle AQ java implementation of enque/deque

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c, ojdbc, advanced-queuing

I have been searching over the internet past few days for any running sample implementation of Oracle Adavanced Queue for enque/deque of messages, but haven't had any success.

I was trying to follow the specification mentioned oracle documentation on this, but it's little unclear to me.

- It doesn't have any information about the dependencies to use (maven/gradle) available publicly. [I came to know that I need to use **aqapi.jar**] . Any specific version compatible with the jdbc driver I am using.
- I am also using c3p0 connection pooling for this and looking for any support of **AQSession** out of the box for the c3p0 to avoid connection and session handling from code perspective.

Note: The queue table and the queue is already setup from the database layer. I am just trying to write a producer/consumer to message delegation. we are using oracle 12c and Java 11.

Any sort of information would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the Oracle JDBC thin driver (ojdbc) to do AQ operations such as enqueue or dequeue. See the [Oracle JDBC Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/toc.htm) for more details about the APIs. Please also checkout this other question on stackoverflow for some code samples:
[How to enqueue on Oracle AQ table on commit with Java and consume with a JMS client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884925/how-to-enqueue-on-oracle-aq-table-on-commit-with-java-and-consume-with-a-jms-cli)

Note you have two options: a) either use the AQ APIs directly or b) use AQ-JMS if you want to use the JMS APIs instead.

aqapi.jar is only needed for admin purposes like "create a queue", "start a queue", etc. Otherwise you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks Jean for the tip. I would really like to use the JDBC provided AQ APIs (No AQ-JMS). The enqueue and dequeue APIs doesn't say anything on the batch queueing and dequeueing. Doing one by one queueing and dequeueing would slow down performance quite drastically.

Comment: You'll get batch enqueue & dequeue through JDBC APIs in the next version of ojdbc. It's not yet released.